# Tree formation issue by the given custom inputs

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, tree

You are given a tree of N nodes rooted at 1. Each node of the tree has a color associated with it. Now you are given Q queries. In each query, you are given a node number X and for each query you have to mark the node X as special and all the other nodes in its subtree with the same color also as special. If a node is marked as special in a query then for all the other subsequent queries, it remains marked as special.
For each query, you need to print the total number of special nodes in the tree after you perform the marking operation in the query.

**Input**
The first line contains an integer N as input denoting the total number of nodes in the tree. Next, N−1 lines contain two integers U and V which denotes there is an edge between the nodes U and V in the tree. 
Next line contains N space separated integers that denotes the color of each node of the tree.
Next line contains an integer Q as input that denotes the count of queries.
Next Q lines contain an integer X that denotes the node whose subtree needs to be marked as special for that query.

**Output**
For each query, you need to print the count of nodes that are special after this query is performed.

**Sample Input:**

```
5
3 1
3 2
2 4
2 5
1 1 2 2 1
4
2
4
5
1
```

**Sample Output:**

```
2
3
3
4
```

**Issue is when I try to change the test case ,the code fails (Runtime error)**

```
5
3 1
2 4
3 2
2 5
1 1 2 2 1
4
2
4
5
1
```

**Expected output must be the same as above**

**Here is the code we have used :**

```
#the result will be shown here.
special=[]
def remove_1_from_tuple(tup):
    if(tup[0]==1):
        return tup[1]
    else:
        return tup[0]
def make_tree(node,hashmap):
    latest=node
    key=latest.data
    if(key in hashmap):
        hmap=hashmap[key]
        for val in hmap:
            latest.children.append(Node(None,val))
        for child in latest.children:
            make_tree(child,hashmap)
class Node():
    def __init__(self, tree, data, parent=None):
        self.special=False
        self.data = data
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []   
        self.tree = tree
    def set_color(self,color):
        self.color=color
    def set_special(self):
        self.special=True
    def find(self, x):
        if self.data is x: return self
        for node in self.children:
            n = node.find(x)
            if n: return n
        return None
    def get_same_color_in_sub_tree(self,x):
        for node in self.children:
            if(x.color==node.color):
                return node
            node.get_same_color_in_sub_tree(node)
        return None
Nodes_length=int(input())
#the tree is a node of 1 (root node)
n = Node(None,1)
node_tuples=[]
while(Nodes_length>1):
    data_A,data_B=map(int,input().split(" "))
    node_tuples.append((data_A,data_B))
    Nodes_length=Nodes_length-1
elem=remove_1_from_tuple(node_tuples[0])
n.children.append(Node(None,elem))
node_tuples=node_tuples[1::]
#create a hashmap..
hashmap={}
for key,value in node_tuples:
    if(key in hashmap):
        hashmap[key].append(value)
    else:
        hashmap[key]=[]
        hashmap[key].append(value)
#now make the tree suign recursive functon...
make_tree(n.children[0],hashmap)
#Assign color to each node..
colors=list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
for index in range(0,len(colors)):
    node_value=index+1
    node=n.find(node_value)
    node.set_color(colors[index])
#get the count of the operations now..
operations_count=int(input())
#run the operations 
while(operations_count>0):
    node_value=int(input())
    CTR=0
    if(len(special)!=0):
        CTR=special[-1]
    node=n.find(node_value)
    if(node.special==False):
        node.set_special()
        CTR=CTR+1
    #traverse throught he sub tree and check if the color is same
    same_color_node=node.get_same_color_in_sub_tree(node)
    if(same_color_node!=None):
        #mark that node as special..
        same_color_node.set_special()
        #increment the counter by 1
        CTR=CTR+1
    special.append(CTR)
    operations_count=operations_count-1
for obj in special:
    print(obj)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int maxn = 1e5;
vector<int> graph[maxn + 5];
bool special[maxn + 5];
int A[maxn + 5];
int res;
int parent[maxn + 5];
unordered_set<int> chalo;

void dfs(int u, int p, int col){
    if(col == A[u])
        special[u] = true;
    if(special[u])
         chalo.insert(u);
    for (int i: graph[u]){
        if(i == p) continue;
        dfs(i, u, col);
    }
}

void dfs1(int u, int p){
    for (int i: graph[u]){
        if(i == p) continue;
        parent[i] = u;
        dfs1(i, u);

    }
}

int main(){
    int n; cin >> n; 
    for (int i = 0, x,y; i < n-1; ++i){
        cin >> x >> y;
        graph[x].push_back(y);
        graph[y].push_back(x);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        cin >> A[i];

    int q; cin >> q;
    dfs1(1, -1);

    while(q--){
        int x; cin >> x;
        int p = parent[x];
        dfs(x, parent[x], A[x]);
        cout << chalo.size() << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the question was looking for a python answer?